# NSArray of file names will not load in NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, nstableview

I am a beginner. I picked up the code for a table created by Jay Versluis on 04/05/2014. It originally had 2 columns and fills the table from 2 arrays. It works. I changed the table to 1 column and have an array reading file names from a directory. The array reads the names fine but nothing appears in my table. Any help would be appreciated.

```
// ——————— Interface —————————
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TableController : NSObject <NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *recipes;
@property NSFileManager *filemgr;
@property NSArray *filelist;

@end

// ———————— Implementation ———————————
#import "TableController.h"

@implementation TableController
static NSString* currentpath = @"/Users/rasweeny/Documents/Current_Recipes";
NSInteger count;

#pragma mark - Custom Initialisers
- (NSArray *)recipes {
    _filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    _filelist = [_filemgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath: currentpath error: nil];
    count = [_filelist count];    
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        NSLog (@"%@", [_filelist objectAtIndex: i]);

    return _recipes;
}

#pragma mark - Table View Data Source
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
    // how many rows do we have here?
    return self.recipes.count;
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {   
    // populate each row of our table view with data
    return [self.recipes objectAtIndex:row];
}

#pragma mark - Table View Delegate
- (void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {   
    NSTableView *tableView = notification.object;
    NSLog(@"User has selected row %ld", (long)tableView.selectedRow);
}

@end
```

Comment: Is there a storyboard or xib associated with this? A lot of the table view properties can  hide in the storyboard.

Comment: What is the value of `_recipes`?

Comment: Yes there is a xib. The value of _recipes turned out to be empty. I have since switched the return value to _fileList which is the filenames in the directory: FirstFile.rtf, SecondFile.rtf, ThirdFile.rtf, FourthFile.rtf. They print out with the NSLog.

Comment: I changed_recipes to _fileList in the other 2 methods also. Nothing still comes up in the table./